# _endthreadex(0) hangs

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have some code which I did not originally create that uses _beginthreadex and _endthreadex.  For some reason, when it calls _endthreadex(0), the call just hangs and never returns.  Any ideas as to what would normally cause this call to hang?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

_endthreadex ends the thread, so it can't return. That's the whole point of calling it.

EDIT: It's a bit unusual to call _endthreadex, normally you just let the thread start procedure return and the runtime calls _endthreadex for you. You may need to explain a bit more, what you are trying to do before we can help.

Answer (score 9):

My answer is too far late, but still someone will use it.

In my case _endthreadex hanged when I unload dll and deleted some global objects. One of global objects had another thread inside and that thread also performed thread exit. This caused deadlock since DLLMain already locked crt memory map. Read DLLMain help and find that you are not allowed do any other action on another threads or processes during DLLMain call.

Comment: Works for me ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Are you mistakenly calling [_endthreadex()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw264s73(VS.80).aspx) to attempt to end a thread from the main thread?

The function [_endthreadex()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw264s73(VS.80).aspx) is meant to be called inside the thread that you want to terminate to report a return value, and for the proper "recovery of resources allocated for the thread."  You shouldn't need to call it in a destructor from the main thread.  You could, in a destructor, signal to the thread via an event (see [SetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686211(VS.85).aspx), called from the main thread) that the thread should exit as soon as possible, and then the thread that is exiting as its last statement would call [_endthreadex()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw264s73(VS.80).aspx).

Calling [_endthreadex()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw264s73(VS.80).aspx) in your main thread would cause the process to hang, because you've terminated your main thread, but you would still have the original thread you wanted to terminate still running.

Answer (score 0):

Ok....well, endthreadex gets called in the deconstructor of my class via "delete classinstance"...and that deconstructor call never returns...so the whole thing hangs

Comment: What is hanging?  The thread that calls _endthreadex is no longer executing, so it can't hang per-se.

Comment: Adam did you find any solution? I just stucked with the same situation. Is it correct to destroy threads from dtors of static objects in DLL?

Comment: So situation is that code tries to terminate thread from destructor of static object during DLL termination phase
what is denied on Windows. It leads to deadlock.

MSDN, Best Practices for Creating DLLs
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487379.aspx

   "Call ExitThread. Exiting a thread during DLL detach can cause the loader lock to be acquired again, causing a deadlock or a crash."